# how to add particles using SpriteKit in iOS7

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, particles, skemitternode

I'd like to add a particle to my SpriteKit app, but I can't find how to do it. I'm able to create using the particle editor, but how do I add them to my view?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: For 2017 **this is now extremely easy**: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43075797/294884

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Lets say that you have a particle already created called MyParticle.sks.

First, you have to create a SKEmitterNode with your particle:

```
NSString *myParticlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyParticle" ofType:@"sks"];
SKEmitterNode *myParticle = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:myParticlePath];
```

Now that the node is created, you can edit some parameters if you want:

```
    myParticle.particlePosition = CGPointMake(100, 100);
    myParticle.particleBirthRate = 5;
```

And the add it to your scene:

```
[self addChild:myParticle];
```

This has to be added to your `SKScene`

Comment: You can refer to the video during WWDC.
Introduction to Sprite Kit
and 
Designing Games with Sprite Kit
https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/

Comment: I gave this a try, but I keep running into an error " No Visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector 'addChild:' " any tips?

Comment: You should add this to an SKScene, not to a UIViewController.

Comment: This has changed a LOT in 5 years, again, this is now very easy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43075797/294884