# SKColor clearColor returning a black color instead?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, sprite-kit

I have setup my `SKScene` the following way during initiation:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {


        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor clearColor];

    }
    return self;
}
```

But somehow, what I am given is the following, which is black, not clear at all:
[image]

What am I missing here? How can I make this scene clear? I have already made the view holding the scene clear yet this is still what I get.

Update: I have also tried setting `myView.opaque = NO;` but this did not help at all.

Comment: the solution is here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/43075797/294884.  there's another thing you have to set to clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting it to clear is working correct, resulting in no colour, so black.

Set to any colour you like via

```
self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: I need transparency, which is the typical result when using `clearColor` @smick

Comment: I have tried doing that but my images becomes stretched out, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780638/how-to-set-the-background-image-for-a-skscene

Comment: maybe change this  [self.scene setScaleMode:SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill];

Comment: `SKView` cannot be made transparent. You can have clear sprites that the scene background shows through, but you can't have other views show through the scene background.

Comment: Is this behavior of SKView verified? You can't make it transparent?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, I messed around a bit trying to get clearColor working and it seems there isn't a way on SKView. I wonder if this is a bug or expected. The only reason why I can see it being expected is to prevent programs from relying on the viewController for the background (ie setting a background image via VC instead of using a SKSpriteNode on an SKScene). Also since after an SKScene is presented, I'm guessing it's expected that you'll be refering to the SKScene at you're controller now instead of the VC that initiated it.

Comment: It might indicate that the SK framebuffer is created as a 16-bit RGB565 frame buffer with no alpha channel, meaning none of the pixels rendered onto an SKView can be transparent. It's the same with cocos2d, for a transparent cocos2d view the framebuffer needs to be created as RGBA8888 (which is quite noticably slower).

Comment: I believe it the same thing with OpenGL ES. You're able to set the GLKView transparent but there is a massive hit on processing. but I didn't know that about the framebuffer.

Answer (score 15):

iOS 8 supports transparency:

```
skView.allowsTransparency = YES;
```

Comment: I placed this as a runtime attribute in Interface builder and it allowed the transparent SKView to actually be transparent with the iOS simulator.  Thx!

Answer (score 2):

After try many things, this worked for me

```
skView.allowsTransparency = true
skView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
view.addSubview(skView)
floatingCollectionScene = BubblesScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
floatingCollectionScene.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
floatingCollectionScene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
skView.presentScene(floatingCollectionScene)
```